# Problem in an axial turbine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbines, ansys

I am simulating an known as , using CFX as a solver.

This turbine have 8 blades((360/8)=45 deg=pitch angle). Due to the circumferential symmetry, only one eight of the annulus has been computed, imposing periodic boundary conditions (periodic rotational) in the tangential direction. The computational domain has been restricted in the axial direction to four chord lengths upstream and six chord lengths downstream of the blade.

Computational domain is as follows:

Also, these are set with specified e. Reference pressure is 1 atm. At the inlet I input a normal speed and at the outlet I have Static Pressure SST as turbulence model setting advanced turbulence controls such as curvature correction and production limiter. Frozen rotor interfaces connect the domains. Rotation domain rotates wit and No-slip boundary conditions are imposed on blade and hub and casing in stationary and rotation domain. and also Rotation domain is set as follows

Also, the values of production limiter and curvature correction and conservation target are default values and

My problem is as follows, there is an error in end of set up in CFX.

Also, Set up of passages in 360 is as follows:

I am grateful that guide me about above cases.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error?  Does CFX just crash catastrophically, or does it print some kind of message?

Comment: @user19061 Why did you remove most of your question?